# JavaScript regular expression ignore case exception (Invalid group)

Tags: javascript, regex, exception

I have the following Regular expression :

```
(?i:(?:(?:(?:fbx|fo))\d+)|(?:(09|0[1-5])\s?(?:\d{2}\s?){4})(?:(@freeadsl)?))
```

I tested the expression in https://regex101.com/ and it works.

[image]

But in javascript, it dosen't work.
[image]

After doing a search, it turned out that the problem is that javascript doesn't accept regex ignore case `?i`.

What's the best solution to remedy this problem.
Any help, i'll appreciate it, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript regex engine does not support inline modifier groups. You may  use a `i` modifier in the JS regex and remove unnecessary non-capturing groups to reduce your regex to

```
var rx = /(?:fbx|fo)\d+|(?:09|0[1-5])\s?(?:\d{2}\s?){4}(?:@freeadsl)?/i;
                                                                      ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dpb5MS/2). The `/i` at the end makes the letters in the pattern match both lower- and uppercase letters.

**Details**:

- `(?:fbx|fo)\d+` -  `fbx` or `fo` substring followed with 1+ digits
- `|` - or
- `(?:09|0[1-5])` - `09` substring or `0` followed with `1` to `5` digit.
- `\s?` - an optional (1 or 0) whitespaces
- `(?:\d{2}\s?){4}` - 4 occurrences of:

  - `\d{2}` - 2 digits
  - `\s?` - an optional (1 or 0) whitespaces
- `(?:@freeadsl)?` - an optional `@freeadsl` substring.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Wiktor. Just for information, i get the regex from Backend, i can't change it but i see that your regex is better, i'm gonna talk about it to backend developper. thank you for your help